# How to get return value from function used in thread in vb. Net

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Public function myfn1(byval pRequest as string) as string
    Dim param(1) object
    param(0)=pRequest
    Dim T as new thread(Addresof myfn2)
    T. Start(param)
End function

Private function myfn2(byval pReq as string) as string
    '////some stuff here////
    Return lstrResponse 
End function
```

Here `myfn1` is accepting requests from user. Sometimes the requests may be concurrent at a time. So I have used thread in `myfn1`. `Myfn2` is actually processing the request and returning the response. So I am willing to get that response in `myfn1` after the thread processed the task. What should I do? Or is there any other way out, Pls suggest

Comment: It makes no sense to start a new thread only to have the original thread wait for its result. Please describe [what you are trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here myfn1 will be receiving bunch of requests from users. The job of myfn1 is to just pass on the incoming requests to myfn2. Function myfn2 will be actually processing the requests and will generate response accordingly. This response I want to return to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using the Async/Await structure : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/

For Doing CPU bound work on a separate thread there are a couple options. I like using `Task.Run()` doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8

You can `await`the task you create and get the result when it's done like:
`SomeVariable = Await Task.Run(Function() FunctionName)`